# All questions with answers are highlighted green in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I'm currently using the beta version of the Stack Exchange iOS App.

However, it seems like all questions, both with and without an accepted answer are highlighted green in the questions list.

I think only questions with has an accepted answer should be highlighted green.

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.0.5
- Device: iPhone 6 Plus
- OS Version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)

Comment: In your screenshot, I see only 3 questions highlighted in green (4, 5, and 7). I'm also using the iOS app on the 6+. Maybe it's a color setting or issue with your phone? Or maybe the colors have become less distinguishable to you in recent app updates? Anyway they're clearly distinguished on my phone when I browse the question list.

Comment: @DanBron There's only 3 questions that is highlighted green. Only these 3 questions have answers; I think only questions with **accepted** answers should be highlighted green?

Comment: Well, I can't tell from a screenshot obviously, but yes given that coloring I would assume those 3 questions have accepted answers. Do they not? Can you post direct links so it's easier for people to double-check?

Comment: @DanBron Yup, they actually don't. I didn't post the links as the answers might get accepted? Anyway, thanks for confirming :)

Comment: They get a filled in "A" icon when the answer is accepted.  The same pattern is used in the Android app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.6.